# Most controversial post, IoC, Ninject, just getting stuff to work

Tags: architecture, dependency-injection, ninject, ioc-container

Where do I start?

Over the course of learning to program one runs into design patterns, architectural choices etc. For me, I understand conceptually DI, IoC and why they are needed/good. Modularity, low coupling high cohesion - I get it.

For example, I am building a small test website with the help of the MVP pattern, where the presenter doesn't have a concrete View, but uses an interface that the View implements. It also has a reference to a service layer (which sits between the presenter and the BLL), again, nothing concrete, using an interface for that. All good stuff.

The (manual) IoC is making the instantiating of concrete objects pushed upwards, to the point that objects need to be injected somewhere, someplace. In other words, the dependency is still there, it is just higher up. Enter IoC containers. And enter frustration.

I know they are there, I know what they are used for. I opted to use ninject. Cool. So, I start looking. In my download I have bunch of files:

- LICENSE.TXT
- Ninject.dll
- Ninject.pdb
- Ninject.xml

another folder, called extensions

- CommonServiceLocator.NinjectAdapter.dll
- CommonServiceLocator.NinjectAdapter.pdb

Okay... a bunch of files. Which to use? I do not know. Where do I place them? Do I need all of them? Questions questions...

Maybe read some manual. Ninject wiki @ github. Right. I start reading - why use Ninject? Dependency Injection By Hand, Dependency Injection With Ninject - nice examples about swords and daggers and such. But I don't read anywhere how to *actually do/use it*. Where do I place it in Visual Studio? How to call it? How?

Also, it presents me with this code:

```
Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
```

It says that everytime IWeapon is called, an implementation of sword is given. Eh... okay, there was a dagger as well - maybe I don't want to get a sword everytime I have e.g. IWeapon as parameter in my constructor, but how to do that? It doesn't say! Am I stuck with a sword everytime I use IWeapon? If not, what is the code to change that then? And how?

It says that when you have a bunch of constructors, it will only take the one with the most parameters. Okay. What does it do with the constructors that have a little less parameter than the constructor with the most? Can't I use ninject with these constructors? Or... how does it work? Again - it doesn't say anywhere. Curses!

In the wiki, there's a link to the *Most Controversial Post* on SO. It is about a guy named Joel how says some things about IoC that enabled the flame war/nerdrage. But you know what? I dare to say that I kinda root for this guy. Why? Maybe the concept of IoC is simple, but by god - getting to the point of finally knowing how to use it, what to do in case of certain situations etc. is really *really* frustrating. Searching google mostly turns up either nothing useful, or indeed a lot to read with convoluted stuff inbetween. I find that the guy might be right in some sense - in that it is really hard to understand concepts and explain to someone who doesn't understand the things you find simple.

Why can't it be more like "Download the files - get this file out and place it somewhere handy, then go to Visual Studio, make a new map and reference the dll. To use it do these steps" and then explaining every step with a very good and detailed why. No snippets of code. It is frustrating.

So, one might wonder what my question is. Well, I want use Ninject. What do I need? where do I place it? How do I get it to work? Do I have to be stuck with a sword everywhere I have IWeapon? What am I doing at work when the sun is shining outside?

Comment: Welcome to the world of open source software ;-)

Comment: Maybe reading a book would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150980/dependency-injection-book-recommendations

Comment: @Mark Seemann - I see what you did there ;-) As I write, I'm reading through the first chapter of your book. So far so good.

Comment: + I'm just thinking how erm... 'ironic' it is that Joel had said something like "...the need to read a 200 page manual on how to use an DI/IoC container" for which he got roasted (since the whole thing should be oh so easy) - and here's a book on the subject :-D

Comment: Obviously I don't agree with Joel, but I think he makes good points that are not easy to dismiss. It's all part of a much larger discussion on whether or not code quality is relevant - just ask Uncle Bob :)

Comment: Post all your questions and we will try to answer them

Comment: @Benjamin: as the person who placed the link in the wiki, I feel I should have added more smileys. At the time of @Joel's post, he was engaging in a variety of wilfully gregarious behavior on the SO podcast around this. It's not what you want to hear either, and proabbly likely to incite you but... it's a wiki - I agree that the many different user constituencies need different ways of learning - perhaps if you can retain your beginner's mind you may be the person to write that. I know the approach of the ninject tutorial may feel a bit out there, but there's not much bad advice in there.

Comment: I personally learnt most about DI from [Bob Martins APPT in C#](http://www.amazon.com/Agile-Principles-Patterns-Practices-C/dp/0131857258/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1301352844&sr=8-2) which is a highly recommended book for me. It works through principles patiently at a level that's simply not appropriate for a DI tool manual which needs to cater to people who are moving over from other frameworks (and some arguably broken assumptions/alaternate design philosophies).

Comment: Highly recommend @Mark Seemann's book and all his writings here (go look at this top answers as a good start to finish education on DI/IoC) and on his blog. And if you find anything else that's a good DI walkthrough from your perspective, post it here or feel free to edit it into the ninject wiki.

Comment: @Benjamin: And if you feel the link to the Joel post/thread is not useful and in fact counterproductive, go remove it - I promise there'll be no edit warring from me. I think the thread as a whole is useful in that the answers as a whole convey the fact that there is something to get and that "I just dont get what all the fuss is about", while easy to side with is definitely not a universally held view. I'll refrain from making allusions to other such dichotomised 'debates' !

Comment: @Ruben Bartelink - I probably won't change anything in the wiki and there were indeed things that I didn't know or probably not well enough that I picked up. I too think the link is useful, be it from the "How The Hell Does this Work?!" guy to the "Ha ha, What is the N00b jammering about" guy and anything inbetween. For me it contained some confirmation of frustration :-D Looking forward to read Mark Seemann's book - so that I may finally be able to use the highly coveted Ninject framework ;-)

Comment: @Ruben Bartelink - In all seriousness though, it is... well, pretty much a letdown when you get to the point where you know (or kinda know) how the stuff leading up to using DI/IoC container works and then when you want to use it you're completely lost. You read and read and you get pieces of knowledge - but the big picture remains somewhat of a mystery. You know, the other pieces of the puzzle to actually get going. Because, is it really that hard? What do others know what I don't know? Is it a matter of experimentation?

Comment: @Benjamin: Note that The @Mark Seemann book doesnt actually directly cover Ninject itself (but Ninject overlaps with the others it does and the princples are the bit you actually want so I have no hesitation in recommending (and preordering) it regardless). I personally learned DI/OC from the Bob Martin APPT in C# then ninjct wiki and then (most imporantly) the ninject tests. There's no magic - DI containers just do a very straightfoward thing in service of the IoC principle. Problem is that people like shiny things and love to use fancy tricery in this space.

Comment: For standard apps, some pretty straightforward bindings and constructor injection are all you need to get a good flow going writing maleanble code that's easy to rejig without having to adjust boilerplate. You can spend a long time agonising about nested containers and stuff but that's mainly just out of control geekery.

Comment: Reading the DI books and stuff everyone else is suggesting probably helps, but frankly Ninject's documentation sucks.  It's a half dozen really simple examples that leave you with no understanding of how to do anything complicated.  (Frankly, that's the same problem with Automapper, terrible documentation.)  Would be nice if there were a Ninject specific book or something...

Comment: Just curious if you got anywhere since you posted this? I'm still running into the issue of finding MVC project samples, or the same IWeapon examples with one kernel.Get<> on a console line... I'm trying to get an example of using it ina regular project that IS NOT in MVC...

Answer (score 6):

I have a very simple set of example code for ninject that I made for some of our developers when we introduced it to our project. It just covers basic bindings and such right now. Not so much with how it works with MVC or more advanced topics like contextual bindings. It's all done as nUnit tests so I hope it's easy to follow. What it does NOT show is how to properly work it into your project. I hope to soon do a true example MVC project.

https://github.com/ryber/Ninject-Examples

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

For web projects I recommend using MVC3. See https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/MVC3 about getting it to work with Ninject.